# Create database from ADO Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've described my model using an Ado Entity Data Model file (*.edmx), and i wish now to generate my db schema and tables from it. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether you are running .NET Framework 3.5 or 4. In .NET 4 it is possible, in 3.5 it is not.

Comment: unfortunately I'm runnig v3.5